# Gatsby & React Context API: Using Context to set languages for internationalization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-context

Currently working on a Gatsby project and attempting to implement i18n/internationalization. I want to serve English and French versions of my site.

I'm following along with [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/techniques-approaches-for-multi-language-gatsby-apps-8ba13ff433c5) to implement this. I'm running into a problem when it comes to using the Context API to create context and pass it to my components. In the tutorial I'm following there is an odd syntax that I'm unsure of:

`const PageContext = React.createContext<PageContextValue>({})`

Here is the full component in which the context is created using `createContext`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

const PageContext = React.createContext<PageContextValue>({})

export const PageContextProvider = ({ pageContext, children }) => {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation()
    i18n.changeLanguage(pageContext.lang)

    return <PageContext.Provider pageContext={pageContext}>{children}</PageContext.Provider>;
}

export const usePageContext = () => React.useContext(PageContext)
```

It produces the following error:

[image]

What is causing this error? I don't know much about the Context API but the `React.createContext<PageContextValue>({})` syntax looks strange and throws an error.

Comment: Its typescript/flow syntax, guessing you not using it so you should just delete it

Comment: I'm not using Typescript. How can I rewrite that line to make it work without using Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

The `createContext` is a [generic method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), so the `PageContextValue` is the type of your context's value.
The tutorial doesn't seem to define this value (which is an issue in my opinion), but you could do so by:

```
type PageContextValue = {
  // Your type definition here
}
```

However, typescript is smart enough to infer the type itself, so you can just create the context:

```
const PageContext = React.createContext({})
```

Note that the type is static once it's defined, so if you actually pass a `{}` that'll be the set type and you wont be able to actually add values to your context, otherwise you'll receive typescript errors. **So make sure to:**

- **Either** define the type as shown above
- **Or** add default values when creating the context to make sure typescript infers it correctly, for example: `const PageContext = React.createContext({counter: 0})` would allow you to access `counter` on your context later without an error.

**Edit**: Just figured out you are not using typescript. The tutorial you've posted is written in typescript! You'll stumble upon more errors if you continue using its syntax so I suggest you just use typescript for your project. But just for this error, it can be fixed removing the generic type (`<PageContextValue>`)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Looking through the tutorial code I don't see a lot of TS in other files. Would adapting the tutorial code be practical?

Comment: From quickly scanning over the tutorial I've only found one more typescript type annotation: `SEO: React.FC<SEOProps>`. If you remove `: React.FC<SEOProps>` you *should* be good to go, but there might be something I've missed. I don't want to criticize something I haven't fully read, but at first glance it doesn't seems like a very weird and incomplete tutorial for mixing JS and TS not even mentioning it.

Comment: I tinkered with it and got it working. Thank you for the help I appreciate it.